# Curious result from PHP, SQL query

Tags: php, sql, calculation

I'm working on an experiment that works with database and I got this odd result.

System goes like this:
I have a button that adds 1 to the counter every time you click it.
Once it reach certain number, it will calculate score deduction and update the score

PHP:

```
$counter = $_POST['counter'];
$user = $_POST['user'];

$sql = "SELECT score FROM board WHERE player = '$user'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if($counter == 1)
  $divisor = 0;
else if($counter == 5)
  $divisor = 0.1;
else if($counter == 20)
  $divisor = 0.3;
else if($counter == 50)
  $divisor = 1;}

$deduction = $row['score'] * $divisor;

$sql = "UPDATE board SET score = score - ".$deduction." WHERE player = '$user'";
```

I started with score = 10
and these are the results

```
Score: 10
Counter: 1

Divisor = 0; Deduction = 10 * 0;
UPDATE ... score = score - Deduction (0)
New score = 10
-------------------------------------

Score: 10
Counter: 5

Divisor = 0.1; Deduction = 10 * 0.1;
UPDATE ... score = score - Deduction (1)
New score = 9
-------------------------------------

Score: 9
Counter: 20

Divisor = 0.3; Deduction = 9 * 0.3;
UPDATE ... score = score - Deduction (2.7)
New score = 6.3
-------------------------------------

## Here is the curious part

Score: 6.3
Counter: 50

Divisor = 1; Deduction = 6.3 * 1;
UPDATE ... score = score - Deduction (6.3)
New score = 0.000000190735
```

Any idea as to why I'm getting the **0.000000190735**?
I'm kinda really confused right now.

B'rgrds,

Comment: It's just a rounding error. Report your answer to anything less than 7dp and it will display zero.

Comment: this is the first time I hear about that rounding error. makes me think how much this occur

Comment: btw do you think it have anything to do with me using data type Float rather than Double?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

This is, no doubt, caused by different representations for `score` and `$divisor` or by the conversion of `$divisor` to a string for the query.  It is hard to specify exactly where the problem is, because there are several different places.

If you really need to handle this, do the calculations in the database:

```
UPDATE board
    SET score = score * (1 - ?)
    WHERE player = ?;
```

Pass the placeholders in as parameters -- rather than munging the query string.

Comment: hmmm let me see how would it turn out and let you know

Comment: btw do you think it have anything to do with me using data type Float rather than Double?

Comment: @null . . . Your code is converting floats to integers and floats to strings in PHP and SQL.  There is lots of conversion.  If you follow this answer, you will eliminate the conversions and probably get the answer you expect.

Comment: Yeah, I actually just found that out. and I tried working with different type and it seems that Decimal works better in most cases than Float and Double.

or at least I think

Comment: @null . . . For many purposes, fixed-point representation do work more intuitively.